# postgis dont work with django

Tags: django, postgresql

this in setting.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
    'NAME':'agricom',
    'USER':'postgres',
    'HOST':'localhost',
    'PASSWORD':'put',
    'PORT':'5433',
  }
 }
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
  execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
 File "/Users/amerah/tutorial_geodjango/lifelngls/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in 
execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/Users/amerah/tutorial_geodjango/lifelngls/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 347, in execute
django.setup()
File "/Users/amerah/tutorial_geodjango/lifelngls/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
  apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/amerah/tutorial_geodjango/lifelngls/lib/python3.6/site- 
  packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
  app_config.import_models()
 File "/Users/amerah/tutorial_geodjango/lifelngls/lib/python3.6/site- 
  packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
  self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
   File
```

here complete000of exception was the apper so see it under this line :

```
 "/Users/amerah/tutorial_geodjango/lifelngls/lib/python3.6/
importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _ 
 find_and_load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in 
  _call_with_frames_removed
 File "/Users/amerah/tutorial_geodjango/lifelngls/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, 
 BaseUserManager
File "/Users/amerah/tutorial_geodjango/lifelngls/lib/python3.6/site- 
 packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
File "/Users/amerah/tutorial_geodjango/lifelngls/lib/python3.6/site- 
 packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 114, in __new__
new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
File "/Users/amerah/tutorial_geodjango/lifelngls/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 315, in add_to_class
value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
File "/Users/amerah/tutorial_geodjango/lifelngls/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 205, in contribute_to_class
self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, 
connection.ops.max_name_length())
File "/Users/amerah/tutorial_geodjango/lifelngls/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
File "/Users/amerah/tutorial_geodjango/lifelngls/lib/python3.6/site- 
 packages/django/db/utils.py", line 202, in __getitem__
backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
 File "/Users/amerah/tutorial_geodjango/lifelngls/lib/python3.6/site- 
  packages/django/db/utils.py", line 125, in load_backend
  ) from e_user
```

here complete000of exception was the apper so see it under this line :

```
  django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 
  'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis' isn't an available database 
   backend.
   Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
   'mysql', 'oracle', 'sqlite3'
```

Comment: You should install the postgis extension in postgresql: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/install/postgis/

Comment: and don't forget include `'django.contrib.gis',` in `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py`.

Comment: unfortunately , i did it before and it doesn't solved ):